# Emacs move-end-of-line, [END], or C-e not moving to end of line?

Tags: emacs, macros

I've noticed that `C-e` `<END>` or `M-x move-end-of-line` doesn't always move the cursor to the end of the line.

Specifically this happens lines wider than the current window, it appears to move to some arbitrary point midway along the line.

Does anyone know if this is expected and more importantly, how to switch it off and make `move-end-of-line`, really move to the END of the line?

(Note: this is also happening in regular non-macro use.)

Emacs version in this example is *GNU Emacs 23.1.97.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)*

#### Update.

The cursor is moving to the char that is on the edge of the window, (the display then re-centers around the cursor.)

Comment: What kind of macro are you doing? I have no issues and I've been using that version as well.

Comment: It happens only on very long lines. this is a regular F3/F4 macro, but also in normal use too. I expect it's a customizable option, set by accident.

Comment: Possibly, have you set it to line warp or to truncate mode?

Comment: `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` is off, and by Warp did you mean Wrap? No they're not on. The visual description is as accurate as I can get, the cursor lands mid line at an arbitrary spot.

Comment: Yeah I mean wrap, sorry about the typo. That's kind of odd. Emacs with --no-window-system or GUI emacs? If it's the first it might be command prompt being weird with mingw for some odd reason.

Comment: Seems that the cursor is moving to the char that sits at the edge of the window.

Comment: Yeah that's the normal behavior, set truncate lines to true and it should work normally. If this works I'll put it as the answer.

Comment: `toggle-truncate-lines` isn't the problem, it's `visual-line-mode`.

Comment: Ahh forgot about visual line mode :P

Comment: and so did I! .. Edited the question to remove the noise about macro mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure `visual-line-mode` is off for the buffer.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the right answer, `visual-line-mode` is very useful, if you deactivate it you'll hide part of the sentence/line of code and you'll have to move the cursor further and further to the right to see the hidden part of the line and that's a real pain especially when coding.

Comment: It's a preference.  For edits it's less useful.  For viewing it's obviously helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Slomojo here (it seems I cannot comment yet).

To add, here is the quote from the Emacs manual:

> In Visual Line mode, some editing commands work on screen lines instead of logical lines: C-a (beginning-of-visual-line) moves to the beginning of the screen line, C-e (end-of-visual-line) moves to the end of the screen line, and C-k (kill-visual-line) kills text to the end of the screen line.

Answer (score 0):

`C-e` is mapped to `end-of-visual-line`, the best solution isn't to deactivate `visual-line-mode` (don't do that especially if you're coding) but to remap `C-e` to `end-of-line` in your init file like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-e") 'end-of-line)
```

Of course I advise you to do the same for `C-a` and to remap it to `beginning-of-line`.

If you think you need to use `end-of-visual-line` and `beginning-of-visual-line` they're still mapped to `end` and `home` buttons respectively.

Comment: It's certainly a way to do it.  However this and similar answers/comments seem to assume that switching anything is somehow static and permanent.  Which bindings tend to be, but a minor mode is often something one would be more likely to toggle as needed.  This is one of those cases.